# EXPORT_SYMBOL() for Windows drivers

Tags: windows, kernel, symbols, device-driver, wdm

Is there any WDM mechanism, similar to EXPORT_SYMBOL under Linux, such that one can use symbols from a driver (A.sys) in another driver (B.sys)?

Answer (score 1):

This is same mechanism as user mode, basically drivers are same PE images as user mode. Simplest approach to mark functions that you wish to export as _declspec(dllexport). And add to header definition _declspec(dllimport):

_declspec(dllexport) void ExportSymbol1(void);
void ExportSymbol1(void)
{
    KdPrint(("exported call\n"));
}

and

_declspec(dllimport) void ExportSymbol1(void);

Also you can use export driver approach (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542891(v=vs.85).aspx)